# Is there a way to get the timestamp of each call from a callstack?

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, callstack

I'd like to use the callstack of a function call when an exception is thrown to get an accurate timelime. 
I know that from a callstack I can get for each call its name and its caller name + line + file. But is it possible to know the timestamp for each called function ?

```js
    function callA() {
        callB();
    }

    function callB() {
        callC();
    }

    function callC() {
        throw new Error('Boom');
    }
```

What chrome console prints is:

```
Uncaught Error: Boom
    at callC (<anonymous>:13:8)
    at callB (<anonymous>:8:2)
    at callA (<anonymous>:3:2)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What I'd like to work with in my js code would be something like :

```
Uncaught Error: Boom
    at callC (<anonymous>:13:8) timestamp : 1559117311448 
    at callB (<anonymous>:8:2) timestamp : 1559117311449
    at callA (<anonymous>:3:2) timestamp : 1559117311449
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)` for seconds from Jan 1, 1970. Or a precise time duration type (start to end) `performance.now()`

```js
function callA() {
  console.log(performance.now());
  callB();
  console.log(performance.now());
}

function callB() {
  let t0 = performance.now();
  callC();
  let t1 = performance.now();
  console.log(`Start: ${t0} End: ${t1}`);
}

function callC() {
  throw new Error('Boom');
  console.log(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000))
}
```

Comment: Hi zer00ne, thank you for sharing it. But I wanted to avoid this solution.
The reason why I want to use a callstack, is that this object is linked to the call itself (here _callC_ in the example).

As in Javascript I cannot identify an execution thread, what if I have some Async call in the stack while calling _callA_ multiple times ?

Comment: You can use `await/async` with a `for...of` loop. Push each function in an array and times for `setTimeout` into another array. Callout each function synchronously with `await`.